# How to write regex to match \s but not \\\s

Tags: java, regex

I want to split a few strings by `\s` but not `\\\s`:

- `ls -a ./dir` -> `["ls", "-a", "./dir"]`
- `ls -a ./to\ dir` -> `["ls", "-a", "./to dir"]`

Is there a way to do it in Java?

Comment: What have you tried? What language? Regex flavor? You just want to split on a space?

Comment: What about `\\\\\s`?  And `\\\\\\\s`?  In order to handle this you will need a lexer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negative lookbehind.

```
(?<!\\\\)\\s
```

If you also want to disallow `\\\s`:

```
(?<!\\)\\s
```

Comment: thanks. I was trying `\\s(?<!\\\\)` all the way wrong.

Comment: how to do **(?<!\\)\\s** for javascript?

Comment: Sadly, JavaScript does not support lookbehind. It might be possible you have to parse the string on your own, or apply hacks like replacing `\\\s` by something else (possibly using regular expressions), match `\s` and do something with it and finally replace back `\\\s`.